Recommendation for summarization model in Hugging Face other than "facebook/bart-large-cnn"
I am currently working on a summarization task and I am using facebook/bart-large-cnn model. This model is very heavy and is very close to the limit of my deployment RAM. Would you recommend any model from Hugging Face that has similar performance but is slightly smaller? I will only use it for english language.
